# Best way to change the primary key for a table in an existing project?

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration, django-migrations

I have an existing Django project with some important data in the database.

But I would like to change the primary key of the main table.

How should I do it? (I am new to Django, so any newbie advice would be appreciated).

I can do it the very manual way of:

- creating a new table as I wanted it to be
- create a python script importing models library and my specific models
- create a loop to copy all the entries from the old model into the new
- do the same with linked models that rely on the old primary key (updating the relation through the new primary key)
- delete old tables
- rename new updated tables to match old tables

Is my approach correct? or is there a simpler way?

Some questions:

- I know I can create custom "migration files" but I feel like doing it manually with Django creating the migration files would be easier. is that fine?
- would old connection (relying on unchanged keys) tables automatically recognize the new renamed table? or will something break if I delete the old table?
- if doing the above, should I remove the "on delete cascade" to avoid linked entries being deleted when I delete and rename the primary-key tables?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @SUTerliakov I am using SQLite and also go t DB Browser. Should I do it through there? I was thinking about it...

Comment: No, I was only talking about db vendor (sqlite), such browsers are evil for complex operations IMO - it's easier to make some subtle mistake. Vendor is important, because you may want to disable constraints temporarily, for example, and it's a dialect-specific task.

Comment: Please add a bit more details to your question. I think he following should be enough: django code for original model, one of dependent models and desired change (django model after a change), all simplified (with unrelated fields and methods excluded). Most probably, it should be possible with migrations (maybe manually written).